# convert ASCII to character in .NET

Tags: c#, html

I am going to save the text box field in database using .net.
If the text box contain "--". then i am going to save the ACSII value of that, means "&#45&#45".

Ex:

```
if Testbox.text = "Hi--";
```

then saving as `"Hi&#45&#45"` in database.

Now, I want to display as "Hi--", while retrieving from database using .net.

yes, we can use Replace(). But i want, Is there any predefine function for decode/encode the HTML ASCII to normal text.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try, where did you fail? What did you get? What did you expect? Thanks.

Comment: It's not "ASCII value", it's XML escape. And you need to provide a list of characters that you want to escape.

Comment: Is there any HTML decode predefine functions or any thing is there?

Answer (score 2):

Your text is not correct(missing `;`s). This

```
var newstr = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Hi&#45;&#45;"); //or HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
```

would return `Hi--`

See [this link](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html)

Answer (score -1):

"Hi&#45&#45".Replace("&#45","-") == "Hi--";

Comment: Is there any HTML decode predefine functions or any thing is there?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Replace method of string class as bellow

```
        //insert into database
        string input = "Hi--";
        input = input.Replace("-", "&#" + Convert.ToInt32('-').ToString());

        //retrive from database
        string output = "Hi&#45&#45";
        output = output.Replace("&#45", "-");
```